# C# Windows form application how to delete selected listbox line and text file

Tags: c#, listbox

I have problem with one function.  Function "Usun" must delete both line in listbox and the same data from txt file** Can anyone help me?

```
using System;

namespace BazaKlientow2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Klient[] lista = new Klient[1];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Write(Klient obj)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Klienci.txt");
        sw.WriteLine(lista.Length + 1);
        sw.WriteLine(obj.Imie);
        sw.WriteLine(obj.Nazwisko);
        sw.WriteLine(obj.Firma);
        sw.WriteLine(obj.NIP);

        for(int x = 0; x <lista.Length; x++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(lista[x].Imie);
            sw.WriteLine(lista[x].Nazwisko);
            sw.WriteLine(lista[x].Firma);
            sw.WriteLine(lista[x].NIP);

        }
        sw.Close();

    }
    private void Read()
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Klienci.txt");
        lista = new Klient[Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine())];

        for (int x = 0; x < lista.Length; x++)
        {
            lista[x] = new Klient();
            lista[x].Imie = sr.ReadLine();
            lista[x].Nazwisko = sr.ReadLine();
            lista[x].Firma = sr.ReadLine();
            lista[x].NIP = sr.ReadLine();

        }
        sr.Close();
    }
        private void Display()
    {
        listaKlientow.Items.Clear();
            for( int x=0; x < lista.Length; x++)
            {
                listaKlientow.Items.Add(lista[x].ToString());
            }
    }
        private void ClearForm()
        {
            txtImie.Text = String.Empty;
            txtNazwisko.Text = String.Empty;
            txtFirma.Text = String.Empty;
            txtNip.Text = String.Empty;

        }

        private void dodaj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Klient obj = new Klient();
            obj.Imie = txtImie.Text;
            obj.Nazwisko = txtNazwisko.Text;
            obj.Firma = txtFirma.Text;
            obj.NIP = txtNip.Text;

            Write(obj);
            Read();
            Display();
            ClearForm();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Read();
            Display();
        }

        private void sortuj_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Sortowanie();
            Display();

        }
        private void Sortowanie()
        {
            Klient temp;
            bool swap;
            do
            {
                swap = false;

                for(int x=0;x<lista.Length -1;x++)
                {
                    if(lista[x].Imie.CompareTo(lista[x+1].Nazwisko) >0)
                    {
                        temp = lista[x];
                        lista[x] = lista[x + 1];
                        lista[x + 1] = temp;
                        swap = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (swap == true);
        }

        private void usun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Usun();
        }
        private void Usun()
        {
            **//i cant do this. this function must delete both line in listbox and the same data from txt file**
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help explain what part you're having trouble with? Your `Usun` function is blank, so it appears you haven't tried yet. StackOverflow is for helping answer specific, targeted, questions, not doing the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

> Function "Usun" must delete both line in listbox and the same data from txt file** Can anyone help me?

You need to read the lines from the file and store then in a `List<string>` memory. You also need to set the `DataSource` property of the `ListBox` to those lines. When you want to remove a line, remove it from the `List<string>` in memory. Then write the whole list back to the file. Then reset the `DataSource` property of the `ListBox`.

Here is an example. In this example, I create a file with "1", "2" and "3" as the lines. Then when the user clicks a button, I remove "1" from the list in memory and write the list to the file. Then I refresh the listbox.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

   private List<string> linesInFile;
   public Form1() {

      InitializeComponent();

      File.WriteAllLines( "Lines.txt", new string[] { "1", "2", "3" } );

      this.linesInFile = File.ReadAllLines( "Lines.txt" ).ToList();
      this.listBox1.DataSource = this.linesInFile;
   }

   private void Remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

      this.linesInFile.Remove( "1" );
      File.WriteAllLines( "Lines.txt", this.linesInFile );
      this.listBox1.DataSource = null;
      this.listBox1.DataSource = this.linesInFile;
   }
}
```